# How to change keyword textarea value in Google Keyword Planner using python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So after successfully login in to google adwords I'm trying to change the textarea value by sending key or by executing javascript. None of the 2 seems to work.
Here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] =("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36")

# driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
email=''
password=''
keyword='plumbers'

driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=adwords&continue=https://adwords.google.com/um/identity?dst%3D/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home&hl=en_US&ltmpl=signin&passive=0&skipvpage=true')
driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys(email)
driver.save_screenshot('testing.png')
signin = driver.find_element_by_id('next').click()
element_xpath = '//input[@name="Passwd"]'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
)
# WebDriverWait(driver,12).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="Passwd"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="Passwd"]').send_keys(password)
# driver.save_screenshot('testing.png')
signin = driver.find_element_by_id('signIn').click()

element_xpath="//div[contains(@id,'gwt-debug-splash-panel-search-selection-input')]"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
)

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click()
textarea='//textarea[@id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area"]'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath(textarea)
)
# driver.find_element_by_xpath(textarea).send_keys('plumbers')
pas=driver.find_element_by_xpath(textarea)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'plumbers'", pas)
```

PS: I forgot the html:

```
<div class="spH-e spic-v">
<div>
<div>
<div id="gwt-uid-64" class="spH-c"> Your product or service </div>
<div class="spk-c spH-d">
<div id="gwt-uid-23" class="sppb-a">
<div class="sppb-b spk-b" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">For example, flowers or used cars</div>
<textarea id="gwt-debug-keywords-text-area" class="spk-a sppb-c" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-64 gwt-uid-23" rows="2" dir="ltr"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="error" style="display:none" role="alert"> Input contains a keyword that is too long. </div>
<div class="error" style="display:none">Your product or service description can't exceed 1,000 words. Remove some words and try again.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: might help if you added the html

Comment: I just added the html...thanks